# Dell Latitude 7350 2-in-1 touchpad issue reattaching in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dell, touchpad

I've got Ubuntu 20.04 up and running on my Latitude 7350 2-in-1 with almost everything working perfectly. My only issue is when detaching the keyboard base and reattaching it again is the touchpad starts using the wrong driver.

By default it shows in `xinput` as `AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint` with full multi-touch support including 2 finger scrolling. But when plugging the keyboard base back `xinput` then shows `PS/2 ALPS Mouse` which loses multi-touch.

If I perform:

```
sudo modprobe -rvf psmouse
```

This removes both devices. Then performing:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
```

Just adds back `AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint` and fixes the issue.

Is there anyway to stop `PS/2 ALPS Mouse` being detected on reattaching the keyboard dock?